# One monodevelop solution, two unity3d projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Is it possible to use one monodevelop solution, which will be used in two unity3d projects?

Why do I need this? I have two almost the same projects (code is the same) with different graphics. I'd like to change code in one place...

Comment: This is a really broad question.  I suggest looking around [the Unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/forum.php?s=8f536fea88d7d870036bdb0017e10ee5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/16908/how-to-share-c-source-between-unity-projects.html), a source versioning software such as GIT or SVN will be a good approach.

An alternate view presented [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/173364/best-methods-for-asset-and-code-reuse-and-organiza.html) is to compile the code into a central DLL that can be shared and used across both projects. This is cumbersome, however, if you will be making many changes as you will have to re-add the dll's to each project every time changes is made (other than that, I would prefer this method). You can see details on this approach [here](http://unite.schellgames.com/).

Hope it helped!